# Java String created with byte[] bug

Tags: java

Why when I run this:

```
System.out.println( "foo" + new String(new byte[] {((byte) 0)}) + "bar" )
```

I get this on console:

> foo

Where is the bar part??

Comment: for me is right after the null char

Comment: it show me `foo bar`

Comment: is it ? for me its coming `foo bar`

Comment: same over here!

Comment: \0 is a very special character ...

Comment: Is this an issue with `console` or `String`? I.e. what happens if you write that string to a file? I suspect it will write successfully and what you are seeing is an artefact of using the console.